# Simple authentication for a Java servlet running in Geronimo

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, servlets, geronimo

I'm just now researching how to add authentication to a Java servlet.  I found [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html) example showing how to use authentication for a servlet, but this is for a Tomcat implementation.  Our production environment uses Geronimo.  How can I accomplish the same thing in Geronimo?

Sorry, just learned the basics around Geronimo the other day yet have yet to find, at a high level, how to require authentication for a servlet running in Geronimo.

Comment: Are you looking for any J2EE based authetication supported by Geronimo?

Comment: For starters I'd like to do a simple user's file as noted in the example I posted.  In that example they suggest adding users to a tomcat-users.xml file.  That is a great first step (for me at least as I have no other authentication methods for this prototype) that I'd like to get working.

Comment: It will be same except setup (tomcat users file).

Comment: @LeosLiterak - so where would I list the users and passwords in Geronimo?  There lies the question - I'm not sure how I do that in Geronimo.

Comment: You can create a database and put a users table where you will store the username and password. So, you can query the table with username and password check against the table. That's the very common way (No Geronimo coupling)

Comment: <geronimo_home>/var/security/users.properties file, see http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC21/installation-and-configuration.html#Installationandconfiguration-Changingtheusernameandpassword

Comment: @Octopus Ahhh, good point.  I guess if I wanted a VERY SIMPLE example I could even store that within the program as well...

Comment: @WildBill Yes, absolutely. You are right

Comment: So I'm still a little lost on this.  Can someone post an example of how to create a simple app that requires SSL to authenticatea servlet runnign on Geronimo (including supporting files?)

Comment: Hi @WildBill Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure it inside the `geronimo-web.xml`. The `web.xml` is similar to the example you provide.

Here a resource that show most part of it:

http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC20/web-application-security-sample.html

In this example the **user** and **password** are in a database.

But it's possible to configure both inside the `geronimo-web.xml` (http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/security-1.1)

---

**EDITED**

This link also provide information about managing `users / groups / realms`.

http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC20/administering-users-and-groups.html

Comment: All servlet containers provide BASIC and form based authentication implementations for you. @edubriguenti has kindly provided you with the relevant documentation links for geronimo. Most of the time this will serve your purpose just fine - with zero lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pac4j library](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j) to facilitate your work.
pac4j supports several authentication mechanisms (form, Facebook, CAS...).

Your question seems to indicate that you are looking for some simple mechanism like form or http basic authentication. In that case, you just need to implement the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticator` interface and rely for example on a file containing the username/password couples. Remember to always use **HTTPS** when submitting the credentials on the wire for saving both confidentiality and integrity.

Take a look at the [j2e demo webapp](https://github.com/leleuj/j2e-pac4j-demo) to see how pac4j integrates in j2e context.

Answer (score 0):

use security filters,they are the best way to implement authentication in servlets,
as-simple authentication for every link would be like this(in web.xml)

```
<filter>
<filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.nawab.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

if you have used convention .do for actions use filters only for actions(in web.xml)

```
<filter>
<filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.nawab.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

you need to make a Class LoginFilter in com.nawab.filters(the address mapped in web.xml)
the code will be written in it's doFilter() method as     LoginFilter.class

```
    public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    // your ipAddress
    String yourIpAddress = "192.168.1.xxx";
    // name you want to authenticate
    String name = "nawab";
    // ip address validation
    if (!request.getParameter(ipAddress).equals(yourIpAddress)) {
        httpRes.sendRedirect("wrongIp.jsp");
    }
    if (!request.getParameter("fname").equals(name)) {
        httpRes.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void destroy() {
}}
```

here chain.doFilter(request, response);
let's the flow to go as it is; else the user is redirected to respective jsp.

Comment: Where is the password stored?  Also, does this send the username as plain text, correct?  If so, how would you secure the traffic and encrypt it?

Comment: for Username Security-
1.Use POST protocol and the username wouldn't be send in the URL.
2.Encrypt the username before sending(by javascript) and send the Encrypted Username,fetch the Encrypted version from database and compare it.

for Password-
1.you must have stored Encrypted password in your database,obviously you will be fetching the password from the database and comparing it.(this was an example to let you know the flow,else everything can be done in doFilter(),as it is in java ,we do these things as developers on a daily basis. :) )